# While loop is skipping last records in Unix Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

File is read using while loop in Unix shell. Code is below.

```
while IFS=, read V1 V2
#Statement
done<$FILE
```

If the $FILE contains N records, The while loop reads N-1 records from the file.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Is there an odd number of records? Because you read two at a time.

Comment: The intention is to read 2 fields in a line. And it is reading 2 fields in a line correctly except the last line.

Comment: Does the last line have a newline?

Comment: how to add newline? Is it by pressing enter after the last record? If yes, No new line.

Comment: If the last line doesn't have a newline (default `read` terminator) then it will return `false` for the last line and the loop will terminate. The normal method for dealing with this is to use `IFS=, read V1 V2 || [ -n "$V1" ]` as the `while` loop condition... or to just ensure that your files are "valid" files and contain a final newline. (Also use `read -r` unless you know you want `read` to interpret backslash escapes and you almost certainly *don't* want that.)

Answer (score 0):

If the last line doesn't have a newline (default `read` terminator) then it will return `false` for the last line and the loop will terminate. The normal method for dealing with this is to use `IFS=, read V1 V2 || [ -n "$V1" ]` as the `while` loop condition... or to just ensure that your files are "valid" files and contain a final newline. (Also use `read -r` unless you know you want `read` to interpret backslash escapes and you almost certainly *don't* want that.)
                    – Etan Reisner